# How to update all attributes of a vue 'observer' with another 'observer'

Tags: vuejs2

I have two vue 'observer' data a and b with the same key value, and I need to replace the value of b with the value of a. If the value of b contains a complex object, I want this complex object to be the value of a. Deep copy copy replacement. I have some ideas: `this.someObject = Object.assign({}, this.someObject, { a: 1, b: 2 })`, but then someObject becomes unobservable. Do you have any good methods? thank you very much

https://codepen.io/yakiler/project/editor/DadznN#

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
    mounted: function () {

  },
  methods: {
    clickMe(){
      let pureData = {...this.copyData.v }; // get a pure data by vue Observer data
      let f = v => v && JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(v)) || {};
      let needUpdateData = this.originData.v;
      let returnValue = Object.assign({}, needUpdateData, f(pureData)); // exec replace value

      console.log('pureData',pureData);
      console.log('needUpdateData',needUpdateData);
      console.log('returnvalue',returnValue);
      console.log('originData',this.originData);
    }
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      originData:{
        v:{a:1},b:2
      },
      copyData:{
        v:{a:0},b:0
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Please provide current code

Answer (score 0):

I would persevere with Object.assign(). You should be able to manage the observers without too much difficulty. The easiest solution is to not have someObject at the root of your component. Create a wrapper for someObject, then when the new value is assigned, the observers will automatically be re-created.

If this is not clear, post some code :-)